# Data added through jQuery ajax does not automatically recognize HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Specifically `<br>`. I have this data stored in my database `Category#1<br>Category#2<br>Category#3`

When I display them after a successful ajax request, I get exactly what was stored in the database. When I try to edit via console, it then will recognize the `<br>`.

How I got the data:

`var category = response.items[index].category;`

How I display it:

`var cat = $('<td />', { text: category }).appendTo(tr);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `html` instead of `text`

```
ar cat = $('<td />', { html: category }).appendTo(tr);
```

Because, if you use `text` it will treat the string as text, which causes the problem.

If you use `html`, it will treat the string as html

Answer (score 2):

change this in your code:

```
html: category
```

---

`.text()` processes the html string as a text so it does not parse it as html if you have html tags in it.
`.html()` method which parses the html string as a html.